# Running mongrel_rails cluster::start on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I have managed to get mongrel_cluster running on my Windows server (v 1.0.5) ok, but I am having trouble trying to get it to spawning all of the (4) mongrel instances.

It launches the first one ok, but then does no more.  That one instance serves just fine, but the others are not launched.  I assume that this is becasue of: "** WARNING: Win32 does not support daemon mode." so its not forking the processes for each instance.

Is there a work arround for this?  Even if I have to start 4 'mongrel_rails cluster::start' manually, thats ok (assumming that they start the correct node of the cluster), or am I better off just launching 4 normal (and speerate) mongrel instances?

I have 2 primary questions:

Is there a way to solve this?
What cool features will I loose by *not* using mongrel_cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you simply CANNOT do what I want to do.  Instead you need to install the mongrel_service gem and run seperate mongrel instances as system services and balance on those.